# Python и акселерометр

Tags: python

Собираюсь писать программу на **python** с использованием акселерометра. Ещё не начал, а уже столкнулся с большой проблемой. Вообще не нашёл статей в интернете про использование акселерометра на python. Нет, конечно я нашёл парочку, но все они очень старые, чуть ли не 2010 года, способы которые там описываются либо не работают на моём телефоне, либо написаны на python2, либо вообще какие-то проблемы с библиотеками. которые либо не работают, либо работают неправильно.
Хотел бы спросить, не знаете ли вы каких нибудь статей на эту тему или на худой конец хотя бы библиотеки, способной на такое.
Пробовал такие библиотеки как sensor и adxl345. Sensor показался мне очень странным, потому что в нём почти нет ничего, что могло бы взаимодействовать с сенсорами, а в adxl345 на компе не устанавливался модуль smbus, а на телефоне ещё при импорте возникала какая-то странная ошибка.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/adxl345/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .adxl345 import ADXL345
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/adxl345/adxl345.py", line 4, in <module>
    bus = smbus.SMBus(1 if int(revision, 16) >= 4 else 0)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

[Program finished]
```

Если объясните в чём проблема этих библиотек, то тоже буду очень благодарен)

Comment: акселерометр это разве не для  Arduino ?

Comment: @Интик, я имел ввиду акселерометр, который в смартфоне. Вместе с гироскопом, датчиком освещения, камерой и т.п.

Comment: может вам стоит попробовать киви ? Kivy is able to handle most types of input: mouse, touchscreen, accelerometer, gyroscope, etc.

Comment: На 100% не уверен, но скорее всего налицо несовместимость версий. очень частая и распространенная при разработке ПО, ситуация.